# Upload file using ftp

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, async-await

I am using Website panel on an IIS server . 
I want to upload a file using ftp

I used this code :

```
try
{
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

     OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
     fd.ShowDialog();

     MessageBox.Show(fd.FileName);

     webClient.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("ftp://" + "username" + ":" +"pass" +"@" + "address/" + "name.ext"), fd.FileName);

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

This code runs without error . when I use file manager of website panel , A file created "Name.ext" but this file size is 0 KB. Why? What is my problem ?!

I am sure that windows firewall allow me to do it.

update : I am doing it with  UploadFileTask and UploadFile (an unasync) but result is same as async :(

Comment: Look at my code, check the response variable and what its returning. It might contain the ErrorCode you're looking for

Comment: Similar question,but not async method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp/15270543#15270543

Answer (score 3):

Your exception might be swallowed inside the unawaited Task which is returning from `WebClient.UploadFileTaskAsync`. You should `await` on your task, that way your `catch` block will detect a potentional exception as it will propogate to the awaited line of code:

```
public async Task UploadFileByFtpAsync()
{
   try
   {
       WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

       OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
       fd.ShowDialog();

       MessageBox.Show(fd.FileName);

       Task<byte[]> response = await webClient.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("ftp://" + "username" + ":" +"pass" +"@" + "address/" + "name.ext"), fd.FileName);

       // You might want to validate the response status code is valid here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        // Do useful exception handling here
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As i said in the comment, check the `response` variable, it contains the response of your upload attempt which might have failed.

**Edit 2**

It seems the issue is with the `KeepAlive` property of the web/ftp request. There is an accepted answer in [The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation. FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815919/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violationthe-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation) and [*here*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/246ffc07-1cab-44b5-b529-f1135866ebca/exception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly?forum=netfxnetcom)

Comment: Yeah , I think you are right . This time it give a error "The uderlying connection was closed : The server committed a protocol violation ." and create file ... Is it a server error ?! can I myself solve it ?!

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that you're not awaiting the Async call and thus whatever process or thread that's running this code might be ending before the `UploadFileTaskAsync` call is actually finished.

Try changing the last call of your try block to

```
await webClient.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("ftp://" + "username" + ":" +"pass" +"@" + "address/" + "name.ext"), fd.FileName);
```

You probably also want to check the return value of the call:

```
var result = await webClient.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("ftp://" + "username" + ":" +"pass" +"@" + "address/" + "name.ext"), fd.FileName);
```

The result object is a `byte[]` of the response from the server.

Comment: I thought it at first and wait a lot of time for it . And change it to UploadFile (An Unasync) but the result is same as  UploadFileTaskAsync :(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a native FtpWebRequest Class to upload a file.

```
     try
     {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(fd.FileName);

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://address/" + fd.FileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Close();

        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
       }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


    }
```